# I need to check the first checkbox for a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using the below code for iterating one object, i want the first check box to be checked. the below code is checking all the checkboxes. Need help

```
 <tbody>
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.rootPersonList}" var="per">
     <tr>
        <th>
           <label class="slds-checkbox">
              <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkPerson" value="true" text="{!per.ID}"/>
              <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
              <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
           </label>
       </th>
       <th scope="row">
          <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!per.FirstName}">{!per.FirstName}</div>
        </th>
     </tr>
   </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Iam using below code
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.rootPersonList}" var="per">
         <tr>
            <th>
               <label class="slds-checkbox">
                   <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkPerson" value="true" text="{!per.ID}"/>
                       <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
                           <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
               </label>
            </th>
           <th scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!per.FirstName}">{!per.FirstName}</div>
           </th>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change from `ui:inputCheckbox` to `lightning:input type="checkbox"`; the former is deprecated and may stop working at any time.

Second, to check just the first one, you can use `indexVar`:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.rootPersonList}" var="per" indexVar="index" ...>
```

...

```
<lightning:input checked="{!index==0}" ...>
```

Or, preferably, include the true/false value directly in your data, so you can write:

```
<lightning:input checked="{!per.selected}" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Comment: mark it as best answer, so it can help others